# WSL - How to disable any option people could login to my WSL Ubuntu (say, with SSH)?

Tags: ssh, login, security, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How to disable any option people could login into a local WSL Ubuntu (say, with SSH)? What steps should be taken right after the WSL instillation?

- I need that I myself should be able to login outwards with OpenSSH.
- There are no webservers or databases on the local WSL.

I believe asking this question is 99% like asking it on regular Ubuntu, but I'm not sure, and hence I ask.

Comment: Do you have concerns about people logging in to your WSL account Windows? (no password prompt for the user, which runs as root by default) I think this might be an equally important concern.

Comment: @JoshuaK thank you for replying. I think whatever user one uses, the very same concern is there - I updated the question to explain what I'm trying to do --- in what context I try to protect Ansible. I now also offer bounty, please re read the updated question.

Comment: @JohnDea Jajuke's answer will take care of the SSH concern, however i have not found a way to prevent someone with access to the logged in Windows user (physical access to terminal) from accessing WSL/shell prompt. I assume you have already changed the default user and set a password, but it still doesn't prompt separately for the password when opening bash, only when executing commands using sudo. I'm interested in a solution though. I've considered changing the shortcut properties so that it runs as admin which would prompt, but it would only address the shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets rephrase what you want:

- Disable ssh server (others can't connect to your machine)
- Enable ssh client (you can connect to other machines)

In fact, the easiest thing is to install `openssh-client` and remove `openssh-server` package:

```
apt-get install openssh-client
apt-get remove openssh-server
```

If you want something different, please clarify.