# Protecting WSL-Ubuntu and WSL-OpenSSH (unfiltering port 443 correctly, to use just these)

Tags: login, security, firewall, automation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use WSL-Ubuntu on Windows 10 home (build 17134.472) basically just for OpenSSH 
and [Ansible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible_(software)) and AFAIK both require only port 443 to be unfiltered to work properly.

I have both *Windows Firewall* and *Windows Defender* to protect the system but I fear WSL (which as of today is under active development) might suffice some security breaches, in some situations.

I desire to maximally protect my WSL to disable any option people could login to it somehow (and maybe also to my Windows through it).

I wonder What steps should be taken right after Installing WSL, updating it (`apt update -y`) and installing Ansible (`apt install ansible -y`).

***Note:*** I only SSH **out** from WSL.

What packages should I install or remove to install such security?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100739/i-cant-use-ufw-on-wsl-ubuntu

Comment: Also related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/865347/wsl-how-to-disable-any-option-people-could-login-to-my-wsl-ubuntu-say-with-s?noredirect=1#comment1814466_865347

Comment: The only solution is on the Windows side and off-topic here as the WSL is just a subsystem, not a full Ubuntu: you need to lock down the Windows firewall.  **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**  **+1** to recover some of your lost rep on this.

Comment: Just a general FYI, Windows supports OpenSSH natively via Microsoft's [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH)  (_**do not** install it from Settings or Chocolatey... use the most up to date version from Microsoft's PowerShell GitHub, linked to above_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Version 1803 allows outgoing connections on all ports

Windows WSL Version 1803 (March 2018) allowed all ports as outgoing connections. Version 1809 (September 2018). However this version was pulled soon after release due to unrelated bugs. Your question doesn't mention which version you are running.

One month ago (Novemeer 2018) From [Redit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/9sn6a3/wsl_support_for_the_builtin_windows_firewall/):

### WSL support for the built-in Windows Firewall

As I understand it the October Windows 10 1809 update finally added WSL support for the built-in Windows Firewall.

Previously, the only way to use WSL was to allow all outgoing connections, as it was not aware of pico.

However, it seems the 1809 update has been pulled for unrelated issues and is and isn't available for download anymore.

I'm on 1803 and I'm wondering if there is any way to get this functionality back or do I have to wait until 1809 is re-released?

History, more info on this: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1852

Comment: Hi, I've added what version I use in an edit. How do you protect your WSL?

Comment: @JohnDoea I'm behind on my Windows updates myself but one was just released 3 days ago for security holes: https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-releases-windows-10-build-17763195-17134472-with-ie-fixes/